# Validating a Data Set.. Which Test should I use

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sampling, sample

I have a data set(size around 1000) which was collected by a third party. I want to verify the correctness of this survey data using random sampling (by telephoning). Is this a correct approach to the verification? Also, which statistical test would be the best choice?

Answer (score 1):

This is a partiel answer on the sampling. 
I guess your sampling should take into account the original sampling used in the survey (whatever that is). For example, let's say the survey was done using stratified sampling. You should choose a proportion to keep (for example 10 % of data so here 100 individuals). And then apply to your sample the same sampling that was done on the initial population with your new proportion. If the initial sampling was purely random, random phone calls are corrects.